# closed Looping AJAX in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have been having some issues lately. Let me explain in depth what I am trying to do.

Right now I have a html file that is running javascript through the `<srcipt></script>` tags. I need to read a file and save it a variable. Then print out the result in the html tag with the class of "orders".
I do this through this line: `document.getElementById("orders").innerHTML += "<p>This will add a new paragraph</p>"` Now part of this is working. I add the text file index.txt as a frame to the page, and read the number of files in a directory (the writing of index.txt is done in another script. I know it works correctly).

Now this is where it gets interesting, I print the number of index into my id "orders" and that works. I also start a loop that goes through every file in a folder, (that ugly clump of strings), and adds it as frame like I did with my first index.txt. Once again this works, you can inspect the html code in my browser and I see that the frames are added. But when I try to print out each text file nothing happens. Can I call the ajax function within a loop? Is it taking to long that is not updating the html script in time? Should I throw my computer against a wall?

Any help is appreciated!

Here is my script:

```
<div id="orders"> </div>
    <iframe id="frmFile" src="index.txt" onload="LoadFile();" style="display: none;"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var index;
        var print;
        xhr.open( 'GET', 'index.txt', true );
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if( xhr.readyState == 4 ) {
                if( xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status<300 || xhr.status == 304  ) {
                    index = xhr.responseText.split('\n');
                    document.getElementById("orders").innerHTML += "<p>"+index+"</p>";
                    for(var i = 0; i < index; i++){
                        document.getElementById("orders").innerHTML += "<iframe id="+"'"+"frmFile"+"'src="+"'"+"/Orders/order"+i+".txt"+"' onload="+"'"+"LoadFile();"+"'"+"style="+"'"+"display: none;"+"'"+"></iframe>";
                        xhrt = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhrt.open('GET','Orders/order'+i+'.txt',true);
                        xhrt.onreadystatechange = function(){
                            if( xhrt.readyState == 4 ) {
                                if( xhrt.status >= 200 && xhr.status<300 || xhr.status == 304  ) {
                                    obj = xhrt.responseText.split('^');
                                    document.getElementById("orders").innerHTML += "<p>"+obj+"</p>";

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    </script>
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be an `xhrt.send(null)` call, or was that a typo?

Comment: A typo. Gee I can believe I forgot that out. Thanks a bunch! @rico0719

Comment: I think if you want to call the ajax in loop.then the xhr.send should be inside the loop

Comment: Your correct. I left out xhrt.send() in the loop entirely. @AbhisekMalakar

Comment: @ICODENUDE Btw, excuse my self-promotion, but your code looks like a prime example of callback hell, which can be solved using Promises. Take a look at my [XHR wrapper function](http://jsfiddle.net/rioc0719/2p6va23c/1/) for an example of using promises to solve your problem.

Comment: @rioc0719 Thanks I will check it out! Just got done with CodeAcademy's html tutorial and ran over here.

Comment: @ICODENUDE Make sure you take a look at [2ality's Promises overview](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-promises-foundations.html) first.

Comment: @rioc0719 Wow. Those are both good references. Thanks for sharing his and yours.